# theme specipic element in form api drupal6

Tags: drupal, forms, module, themes, cck

how can i theme a specipc element that created by node form? i saw mytheme_checkbox etc but i want to do phoneselect_theme() { } and change there the value or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Theme Developer module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) to find which function or template file is outputting the part of the page you're interested in theming. Theme Developer will also tell you what "suggestions" you can use to override the output. Check out the [Theme Developer screencast](http://drupal.org/node/209561) for an introduction on how to use the module.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [form alter hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6) in your module, and then use the [#theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#theme) attribute inside the alter hook to override the form element's theming.

You'll want to know the exact form ID of your form. [This writeup](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6) by Lullabot will tell you how to find the form ID and it will give you an example of how to modify forms.

Don't forget to register your new theming function using [the theme hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6).